# Приставка с буквой  "З" в русском языке

Tags: словообразование

Правда ли, что в русском языке нет приставки с буквой "З"?

А в историческом русском тоже не было приставки "З"?

Comment: @Федя, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 7):

Орфография приставки «с»  связана с орфографией других приставок на з/с,  написание которых всегда отличалось большой нестабильностью. Это связано с тем, что эти приставки изначально не имели редуцированного гласного «ъ» на конце, как другие приставки, поэтому уже в дописьменный период фонетическое чередование з/с стало отражаться в устной речи, а потом закрепилось и на письме .

Но уже с 13 века  наряду с таким традиционным (фонетическим) письмом  появляется фонематическая запись приставок через «з». Противостояние этих двух принципов (с колебаниями то в сторону одного, то в сторону другого )  длилось до середины 19 века, когда окончательно установился фонетический принцип для всех приставок, кроме «без» и «чрез», а после 1918 года он распространился и на эти приставки.

Что касается приставки «с», то  делались **только отдельные попытки  записи   «з» перед звонкими согласными** (сщет, но: зжечь, збор - примеры из документов 17 века) в те периоды, когда начинал преобладать фонематический принцип.

**Интересно:** А.С. Пушкин старался проводить в орфографии фонематический принцип написания слов с приставками с сохранением "з" во всех случаях и перед звонкими, и перед глухими согласными: разчет, розчет, до возтребования,изпугали, изкупленье, изтаила, произшествие, снизхождение, изключили, разпечатывать, возклицает; значительно реже Пушкин пишет:происшествие, испрасить.

Comment: Выходит, нынче в русском языке не сохранилось приставок с буквой "З"?

А в слове ИЗВОЛИТЬ есть приставка?
ИЗВЕРГНУТЬ, ИЗБИТЬ, ИЗЪЯВЛЯТЬ? 
Кажется, подобных слов много.

Кроме того - РАЗДАТЬ, РАЗБИТЬ и т.д.  в этом роде.

А слово ЗДОРОВЬЕ? (З+ДАР).

Comment: Вопросы надо задавать корректно, и не надо будет самому на них отвечать некорректным способом. Приставка Из содержит букву з. Но вопрос так и задан, что понимается буква з в отдельности, а не в связи.
Здоровье--это тоже неправильный ответ. Здравие--исходник, а не дар. Скорее сравнение с деревом, древом. А дар-оттуда, из дерева. Фасмера тут трудно перешибить. Скипидар, к примеру, продукт перегонки живицы, кипячением.
а дальше скип.

Comment: Вопрос был поставлен такой:
Правда ли, что в русском языке нет приставки с буквой "З"?
Так что всё было корректно.

Иначе бы вопрос звучал так: Есть ли в русском языке приставка "З"?

Чувствуете разницу?

Answer (score 1):

Почему не было.. есть!!
-ЯТЬ  в словаре Фасмера.
(реконструкция) *-ьму: взять, возьму (см.), снять, занять, займу, нанять, обнять, отнять, поднять, понять, внять, изъять, принять, снять и т. д., ст.-слав. възти, възьм. Дальнейшие родственные формы см. на взять, емлю (выше). Ср. лит. imti, imu, emiau "брать", лат. еmo, emi, emptum, -еrе "брать"; см. Бернекер I, 430; Вальде – Гофм. I, 400 и сл.; Френкель, Lit. Wb. 184 и сл. Об отношении к гот. niman "брать" см. также Кречмер, "Glotta", 19, 209; Торн 293.

Судя по такой постановке вопроса, Зять--как раз из этой серии.  з приставка.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. 
Теперь буду знать, что в русском языке есть приставки с графемой "З".